# Integrating Touch ID with Firebase Auth in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, touch-id

I'm new to React native but I have created a signup / login which uses the react-native-firebase package (based of https://github.com/faahmad/react-native-firebase-auth), I want to incorporate touch id to allow a user to login, but I can't find any examples online (in react native with firebase). I have had a look at the packages react-native-fingerprint-scanner and react-native-touch-id which are straight forward to implement I just don't know how to tie firebase auth and touch id together. Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just a thought and not yet implemented as 'actual code' but... Here's my two cents on how I would approach it:

Once the user signs-up, you can store their email and password with [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage), [SQLite](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) or whatever. And then add `Login with fingerprint` as a feature inside the user's settings page. From there, once the user decides to login again, you can:

1- Use the promise that `react-native-fingerprint-scanner` gives you.

2- Fetch the email and password from your database of choice.

3- Use that data to authenticate with firebase and login.

It will look something like that:

```
handleLogin() {
    FingerprintScanner
        .authenticate({ description: 'Scan your fingerprint to login' })
        .then(() => {
            const sql = "select email, password from user";
            db.runQuery(sql, function(data) { // this is a made-up function
                const { email, pasword } = data
                firebase
                  .auth()
                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                  .then(() => /*navigate to main page once authenticated*/)
                  .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message 
            });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

There are rooms for improvement but this should work for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, just in addition here is a link https://blog.theodo.fr/2018/04/add-touch-id-react-native-app/ (I haven't reviewed it completely yet but it addresses the storage of passwords using a keystore /keychain).

Comment: How do you know that a particular fingerprint is associated to which id?

Comment: on iOS this is possible only because only one single Apple ID is allowed per iOS device.  But on Android you can have multiple Google accounts added and managed on a single device.  In such a scenario, it is not possible to know which fingerprint is associated with which account 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286516/how-to-identify-a-user-based-on-his-fingerprint