# How to identify a user based on his fingerprint?

Tags: android, fingerprint, user-identification

I'm working on project which require fingerprint authentication. Which I've achieved already , now I'm curious about can I identify a mobile's users based on their fingerprint ?

If yes then please guide me with your wisdom , thank you.

I'm using this sample code 'https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. There's no such method in `Fingerprint` API (deprecated) and the recent `BiometricPrompt` API to identify the scanned prints, they can only acknowledge about the validation of the scanned fingerprints (i-e valid or invalid) as per [Google Compatibility Definition for Android vendors](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no such provision to identify user directly if you use any either of [Fingerprint](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#fingerprint-authentication) API or [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt) API. API allows callback to authenticate user through fingerprint or other supported biometrics validation methods, but doesn't have option to identify user uniquely.

However if you are doing validation using external validation devices and their supported SDK, then you can map individual fingerprint with their fingerprint data allowing you to create authentication mechanism for individual user.